# How to bend a 2D mesh with more than one armature bone?

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

[image][image: my animation[![pipe bent]
As you can see I had no problems bending a 3d mesh with 2 bones, but I had no such luck with 2D animation I'm trying to do.

I'm trying to make a wing flap for my animation. I want the wing to bend in an up and down motion when I animate it, but first the mesh needs to be able to bend.

Or is it possible to bend a mesh with a single bone? or in other words can you bend an armature bone?

(ADDED) sorry you guys, normally when you want to bend an object you would need 2 or more armature bones.parent the bones to the mesh, then put weight on the mesh etc . I'm trying to do that with a 2D mesh but not having much success. p.s i'm using a computer that cant screenshot

Comment: Please, no caps. Provide some screenshots.

Comment: One bone for wing, second one for flap and properly set vertex groups.  Be more specific where is problem.

Comment: Please provide further information. As LukeD already said, images are always nice. Write your question in a way it's easy for us to understand and to answer it. The better the question the better the answers. And questions that are only written in caps appear a bit repulsive. If you really need an answer take your time to write a good question.

Comment: Please provide more detail to your question. Some screenshots, or better the current blend file uploaded to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ would definitely help. Also add what you've tried so far to solve the problem.

Comment: You can make bending with shapekeys and use drivers to adjust the shapekey with the angle of the bone.

Comment: sorry you guys, normally when you want to bend an object you would need 2 or more armature bones.parent the bones to the mesh, then put weight on the mesh etc . I'm trying to do that with a 2D mesh but not having much success. p.s i'm using a computer that cant screenshot

Comment: Blender supports screenshots natively. Go to *Window > Save Screenshot*. And what exactly do you mean with "2D Mesh"?

Comment: To make a screen grab on blender press Ctrl F3 and save the image.

Comment: do you guys need more screenshots to get a better idea?

Comment: First you need enough geometry to distort part of the image, if you only have a 4 vertex plane you can only squash/stretch or shear the whole image. Some of [these videos](https://www.youtube.com/user/albinal/videos) include examples of how to animate 2d images.

Comment: the videos dont show step by step guides of how to do it but jst show what I want to achieve without commentary. Can I get some pointers on how to do it?